# Homography matrix in android opencv

Tags: android, image, opencv, transformation

I am rewriting the following code of warping two images on android for which I need to find the equivalent statement of 1st in android opencv. Please help.

```
    std::vector< Point2f > obj;
    std::vector< Point2f > scene;
    Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );
    // Use the Homography Matrix to warp the images
    cv::Mat result;
    warpPerspective(image1,result,H,cv::Size(image1.cols+image2.cols,image1.rows));
    cv::Mat half(result,cv::Rect(0,0,image2.cols,image2.rows));
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV [findHomography Javadocs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/calib3d/Calib3d.html#findHomography%28org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f,%20int,%20double%29).

```
Mat H = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene, Calib3d.RANSAC, 8);
```